# create file with fields

Tags: javascript, r, node.js

I want to create a file in a specific format.

For example , I want the file to be able to hold the filename , a color and a description.

1 ) The files should be  like: `filename.txt RED GOOD`

I want later to run an R script using as input this file.

`R --args FileWithSpecificFormat outputfile < Rscript.R`

2) Also,what if I have many files that I want to pass as input to r script?

For example, I have :

`filename1.txt RED GOOD`
`filename2.txt GREEN BAD`
....

and I want one `FileWithSpecificFormat` (but contains the above 2 ) to pass as input to R script.

Comment: This question aught to win an award for vagueness.  Decide what kind of file you want, CSV, JSON, XML and then learn that file format.

Comment: @ShamSUP:I can create a file ,but in such a way I can't figure a way , that's why I haven't posted any code

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher:Just a txt file with empty spaces between

Comment: I don't understand this at all. How are you creating these .txt files? Are you trying to create them in R? Where is the data coming from - the "RED" and the "GOOD"?

Comment: @EatPeanutButter: ( nice username :) ).These txt files will be my input.I will not create them.I want just to create a pattern in order to provide it as input to the R script.So , the filename will have 3 fields.The name of the file , the color and a description.I hope it is clear now?Thanks